# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder

Tags: java, netty, maven-dependency

I am trying to implement [relayrides/pushy](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy), but am getting the following runtime error:

> ```
> Jun 28, 2017 2:06:58 PM com.turo.pushy.apns.SslUtil getSslProvider
> INFO: Native SSL provider not available; will use JDK SSL provider.
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder
>   at com.turo.pushy.apns.ApnsClientBuilder.build(ApnsClientBuilder.java:396)
>   at com.jobs.spring.service.NotificationServiceImpl.sendIOSPushNotification(NotificationServiceImpl.java:122)
>
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder
> ```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Push Notifications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
        <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.27.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ning</groupId>
        <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.40</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**java**

```
    final ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder()
            .setClientCredentials(new File(PATH_TO_P12_CERT), CERT_PASSWORD )
            .build();
```

I am guessing my mvn dependencies are incorrect. Any help appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I updated my dependencies to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
        <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

But now get:

> ```
> Jun 28, 2017 2:40:18 PM com.turo.pushy.apns.SslUtil getSslProvider
> INFO: Native SSL provider not available; will use JDK SSL provider.
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.config()Lio/netty/bootstrap/BootstrapConfig;
>   at com.turo.pushy.apns.ApnsClient.<init>(ApnsClient.java:172)
>   at com.turo.pushy.apns.ApnsClientBuilder.build(ApnsClientBuilder.java:420)
>   at com.jobs.spring.service.NotificationServiceImpl.sendIOSPushNotification(NotificationServiceImpl.java:121)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

seems like you mix netty 4.1 and 4.0. You need to only use 4.1 if you want to use pushy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean your classpath in between I created a test project containing only the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
    <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
    <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

and a simple main class just creating the client with the snipped you are using above and it works out fine

To me it looks like there might be two versions of BootstrapConfig on the classpath. Try to remove all dependencies besides pushy and clean/refreshing the maven dependencies.